# how to represent large dataset in simplified form

Tags: mysql, database-design

We have a table attendance_details in MySQL that has  attendance details for five courses. This table has millions of records.

table structure is

```
training_date - date on which training happened  
student_id - id of the student  
course1 - no of hrs attended  
course2 - no of hrs attended  
course3 - no of hrs attended  
course4 - no of hrs attended  
course5 - no of hrs attended
```

I need to expose the information to another app which will query the attendance details.
and the query pattern is always "did a given student attend course4 all the day between date1 and date2 ?"
*if the student attended atleast one hour for that day then it will be considered as attended.*

**the result could be**

1. attended all the day between date1 and date2
2. attended between date1 and date2, but absent for some days
3. not appeared at all between date1 and date2

I need to provide data in simplified way in new table, so that another app can get the details by querying.

**my objectives are**

1. reduce no. of records substantially in new table, so that the query would run fast. **faster querying is main objective**
2. data model should be easier for querying

**constraints :**

1. i do  not want to expose attendance_details, just because it is huge and highly transactional.
2. it is not possible to chanage structure of attendance_details.

**Below is what i have tried**

table to represent first & last attendance date, first & last absent date

```
 +------------+------------------+-----------------+--------------+------------------------+
| student_id | first_attendance | last_attendance | first_absent |      last_absent       |
+------------+------------------+-----------------+--------------+------------------------+
|        123 | 2015-01-01       | 2015-01-30      | 2015-01-15   | 2015-01-21             |
+------------+------------------+-----------------+--------------+------------------------+
```

in above table design the dates become specific to courses. hence i need 4 courses x 4 columns, totally 16 columns. this will increase if i add more courses.

Also attempted to represent each month records as bitmap , but that makes programming logic complex.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. We could help you better that way.

Comment: So you are interested in only course 4??

Comment: actually i have 20 courses. for simplicity i posted with just 4.

Comment: What you need isn't tables but VIEWs

Comment: @e4c5 what info should the view has to expose ?

Comment: Please refer to the section titled views in the mysql manual. Essentially it's like creating a new table but the table does not exist physically so there is no duplication of data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say you're close.

Let's go over the relationships.

- A student takes 1 or more courses.
- A student attends a course all days between 2 dates.
- A student attends a course some days between 2 dates.
- A student did not attend a course between 2 dates.

So let's look at the object tables first.  I'm assuming there's a Student table and a Course table already in the database.

The first table is a junction table of Student and Course.

```
StudentCourse
-------------
Student ID
Course ID
Course Started Date
Course Ended Date
```

The primary key is (Student ID, Course ID).  This allows us to query on the courses that a student is taking.  We also have a unique index on (Course ID, Student ID).  This allows us to query on the students attending a course.

Now that we've established the start and end date of the course, we can keep a record of each student's attendance,

We need one more class to complete the relationships, Attendance.  Here's what attendance looks like.

```
Attendance
----------
Student ID
Course ID
Start Date
End Date
Is Present
```

This table has a primary key of (Student ID, Course ID, Start Date).  There's also a unique index on (Course ID, Student ID, Start Date).

The idea here is that for each student, you create enough rows to describe a student's presence or absence on a particular range of dates.  If you want to make this easier, remove the End Date from the table, and you'll have a row for each date of the class.

I'm not sure what your example row is telling me, but here's what I mean.

```
Student ID     Course ID     Start Date     End Date     Is Present
    123            456       2015-01-01     2015-01-14      true
    123            456       2015-01-15     2015-01-21      false
    123            456       2015-01-22     2015-01-31      true
```

Since all of the dates are covered, you can query using the SQL clause WHERE "Start Date" IS BETWEEN date AND date to get the rows you want.